# Can we develop mobile browser based Chat application without using WEBRTC?

Tags: iphone, mobile, browser, webrtc

I need develop chat application in mobile browser(android,iphone) as no mobile browser supports WEBRTC most of my browser based chat app is not working in mobile(android,iphone), there is any way develop mobile browser application that works in mobile browser ?

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't answer your question, but the WebRTC APIs are available on Chrome for Android (currently in Beta behind a flag) and implementation is planned for Opera on mobile and desktop. That means a lot of mobile and desktop devices with full support for WebRTC...

Comment: is it possible to create webbased chat application that will work in all browser both mobile and desktop..Please help

Comment: Not with WebRTC. Not sure about other solutions, using Flash or whateve -- unlikely that any solution will work in *all* mobile and desktop browsers.

Comment: i tried to develop application using jquery.It is simple from camera drawing to canvas and writing it into base64 text format in setinterval 20 images peer second and in other file getting that image in same speed it work but have some drawback. first of all i need to know is right way of doing it. it is too slow and is there any way of sending sound with that . thanx in advace